# find_element_by_class_name returning NoSuchElementException when it is clearly present

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a script using Selenium that is supposed to routinely download this .csv file from Box: https://osu.app.box.com/v/covid-19publicdata, but I am having issues finding the button element.

The HTML code for the button looks like this:

```
<button class="btn tooltip-target tooltip-element-attached-top tooltip-element-attached-center tooltip-target-attached-bottom tooltip-target-attached-center" type="submit" data-resin-item_id="725957383895" data-resin-target="download" tabindex="0"><span class="btn-content"><span>Download</span></span></button>
```

To find the button and click it, I wrote the following code (which is run after importing the appropriate libraries):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/calle/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://osu.app.box.com/v/covid-19publicdata")
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn tooltip-target tooltip-element-attached-top tooltip-element-attached-center tooltip-target-attached-bottom tooltip-target-attached-center")
button.click()
```

However, even though the class name I am searching for is the exact same as the one on the driver, it is returning NoSuchElementException on the "find element" line. I haven't really been able to find any information about why this might happen. I'm not a computer scientist, so any help on this would be appreciated. I'm also not really attached to this specific method, so if there's generally an easier way to do this, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

Try with XPATH,

```
webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/calle/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://osu.app.box.com/v/covid-19publicdata")
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[5]/span/div/main/div/div/div[1]/header/div/div/button/span/span')
button.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code was that it was a compound class name which is multiple class names. It wouldn't work with class_name. There is an easier selector to use.

```
button=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-resin-target='download']")
button.click()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and was super easy to implement, thank you!